# VSTS Use repository created locally

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I created a local Git repository for a project I was working on and then pushed it to a newly created repository on Visual Studio Team Services.

All this seemed to work just fine and I can make changes locally, commit and push them, and see them show up in the web interface.

Strangely though, if I try to open the server repository (Team Explorer>Manage Connections>Connect to Team Project), I receive a message to "clone this repository to start developing".

Since I already have a local (and up-to-date) clone, that doesn't seem right. I cannot however, even see the solutions in the repository before doing so.

How do I tell Visual studio that the local repository **is** the clone of the server repository?

Comment: Your first step seems culpable to me.  Typically, you would clone an existing repository.  Or, if you're intention is to populate an empty repo, there would be one or more special steps you would take in the beginning.  Maybe expand on the first sentence of your question.

Comment: When you create a new project on VSTS, it gives steps to push an existing repository from the command line, and that's what I did. It involves a `git remote add` followed by a `git push -u`.

Comment: Fair enough +1.  These comments will hopefully add to your question.  Strange bug; I don't have an answer.

Comment: @CobusKruger please make sure you connect with the new create VSTS repo correctly. Can you share the screen shot of the VS team explorer with remote repo and local repo (as this example https://ibb.co/mYJ608, VSTS test2 repo is connected with the local repo).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the local git repo you created is not added under VS **Local Git Repositories**.

You can add your local git repo’s directory into Local Git Repositories in Team Explorer, then connected to the VSTS project, it should not hint the message to clone now.

[image]